# Как указать воронку при интеграции заявок с сайта в Битрикс 24?

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24, crm

Настроена простая интеграция сбора заявок в Битрикс 24

```
<?php
define('CRM_HOST', 'login.bitrix24.ru'); // Указываем Ваш домен в CRM 
define('CRM_PORT', '443'); // Порт сервера CRM. Установлен по умолчанию, не меняем
define('CRM_PATH', '/crm/configs/import/lead.php'); 
define('CRM_LOGIN', 'login@it-blog.ru'); // Логин пользователя Вашей CRM 
define('CRM_PASSWORD', 'pass'); // Пароль пользователя Вашей CRM 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
    $name = $_POST['name'];// Получаем данные из поля Имя
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // Получаем данные из поля Телефон
    $usermail = $_POST['email']; // Получаем данные из поля E-mail
    $product = $_POST['product']; // Получаем данные из скрытого поля названия товара
    if(!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
        $comment = $_POST['comment']; // Если есть комментарий, то получаем поле Комментарий
    }
 
   $postData = array(
      'TITLE' => 'Заявка с сайта', // Заголовок для лида
      'NAME' => $name, // Имя
      'PHONE_WORK' => $phone, // Телефон
      'EMAIL_WORK' => $usermail, // E-mail
      'COMMENTS' => $product.' '.$comment // Пользовательский комментарий
   );
   if (defined('CRM_AUTH'))
   {
      $postData['AUTH'] = CRM_AUTH;
   }
   else
   {
      $postData['LOGIN'] = CRM_LOGIN;
      $postData['PASSWORD'] = CRM_PASSWORD;
   }
   $fp = fsockopen("ssl://".CRM_HOST, CRM_PORT, $errno, $errstr, 30);
   if ($fp)
   {
      $strPostData = '';
      foreach ($postData as $key => $value)
         $strPostData .= ($strPostData == '' ? '' : '&').$key.'='.urlencode($value);
      $str = "POST ".CRM_PATH." HTTP/1.0\r\n";
      $str .= "Host: ".CRM_HOST."\r\n";
      $str .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
      $str .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($strPostData)."\r\n";
      $str .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
      $str .= $strPostData;
      fwrite($fp, $str);
      $result = '';
      while (!feof($fp))
      {
         $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
      }
      fclose($fp);
      $response = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result);
      $output = '<pre>'.print_r($response[1], 1).'</pre>';
   }
   else
   {
      echo 'Connection Failed! '.$errstr.' ('.$errno.')';
   }
}
?>
```

Но в Битриксе есть особенность в том, что несколько воронок(туннелей продаж),  по умолчанию все заявки идут в первую воронку, как при интеграции указать, в какую воронку должна идти заявка?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по Вашему примеру, Вы отправляете заявки в лиды.
В битрикс в лидах нет воронок.
Воронки (направления продаж) есть в сделках.

Если хотите отправить заявку в конкретный СТАТУС лида, используйте поле **STATUS_ID**.
Если же цель - отправлять заявки в разные направления сделок - используйте методы по работе со сделками.
За конкретное направление и стадию сделки отвечают поля **CATEGORY_ID** и **STAGE_ID**

Comment: как получить STAGE_ID?

Comment: Вариант 1: через консоль браузера - Инспектор. Перейти в настройках CRM, Справочники, выбрать нужное направление сделок - затем выделить интересующую стадию и в инспекторе в DOM-дереве смотрим значение "value"

Comment: Вариант 2: использовать rest api. Метод crm.status.list (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/auxiliary/status/crm_status_list.php). Запрос может выглядеть примерно так: crm.status.list?filter[ENTITY_ID]=DEAL_STAGE&order[ENTITY_ID]=ASC

Answer (score 1):

Уточняю для новичков.

1. При использовании crm.lead.add нельзя отправить лид в другую воронку продаж: в методе нет параметра, который отвечает за это. См. https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/leads/crm_lead_add.php
   Такой параметр есть в методе crm.deal.add - добавление сделки. Это параметр CATEGORY_ID. Т. е. только созданную сделку можно отправить в нужную воронку, а лида нет. Но в сделках, создаваемых через вебхук нет имени, человека, контактов... (См. документацию).
2. Узнать CATEGORY_ID нужной воронки можно так:
   зайти в битриксе в раздел CRM - Настройки - Настройки CRM - С чего начать - Воронки продаж
   Откроется таблица воронок. На этой странице открыть инспектор кода и навести на чекбокс слева от названия нужной воронки. У этого input type=checkbox смотреть value или id. Число в этих атрибутах и есть id воронки.